# How to view MathJax markup while an edit is pending

Tags: bug, mathjax, suggested-edits

I will often blockquote from OP's question, especially when I want to steal OP's MathJax markup rather than re-write it myself.

However, when an edit is pending I know of no way to view OP's MathJax. In particular, when I click on the "Edit" button, I can't view the MathJax, I can only approve the edit (and I don't have the authority to fully approve on my own), and therefore I can't view OP's MathJax when an edit is pending.

Is there any way to view OP's MathJax when there is an edit pending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not already approved the edit, then when you hit the Edit button with an active edit suggested, select the option "Reject and Edit", which will open up the editor where you can view everything written. It won't actually reject the edit until you press the Submit button at the end, so you will still be able to cancel and then approve.

Note that you can always right-click on the rendered MathJax and select "Show Math As..." option, then the "TeX Commands" option, which will open up a new window with the tex commands (obviously) that you can copy & paste into your answer.